# Divide a list of tuples and integer value python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function which calculates term frequency, but `total_words` is an integer value and `most_common` is a list of tuples, how can I divide those to?

Output of `total_words`:

```
1574
```

Output of `most_common`:

```
[('the', 1074), ('to', 790), ('a', 586), ('of', 535), ('and', 434)]
```

Code:

```
def tf(filename):
    with open(filename) as input_file:
        count = Counter(word for line in input_file
                             for word in line.split())
    total_words = len(words)
    most_common = count.most_common(5)
    
    tf = []
    for i in most_common:
        tf.append(i/total_words)
    
    return tf
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'int'
```

I've tried to look at other questions on stack overflow, but could not find any solution which works.

Comment: What is in the list of tuples?  If you only want the first element, then just do `tf.append(i[0]/total_words)`.

Comment: See the output of `count.most_common(5)` and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: `words` is not defined. Please provide a [mre] with complete code as well as example input and desired output. If `most_common` is all correct, then for the sake of example, just use that and remove the file reading stuff.

Comment: @TimRoberts I want to divide all values in `most_common`

Comment: @enzo `most_common` output is: [('the', 1074), ('to', 790), ('a', 586), ('of', 535), ('and', 434)]

Comment: Here, I made [a gist](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/1e03de10aecc9819ffd61e4c43a56af6) that I think is an MRE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second element of each tuple is the actual frequency (while the first element is the word).

See the documentation for [`most_common`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common).

```
tf.append(i[1] / total_words)
```

Answer (score 1):

With [tuple unpacking](https://treyhunner.com/2018/03/tuple-unpacking-improves-python-code-readability/), you can make it clear in your code what the structure of the `most_common` list is (that is, a list of `(word, word count)` tuples). It seems you're only interested in the counts.

```
frequencies = []
for word, word_count in most_common:
    frequencies.append(word_count / total_words)
```

This could be condensed into a [list comprehension](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/):

```
frequencies = [word_count / total_words
               for word, word_count in most_common]
```